# Evaluate $\int \sin^5{(x)}\cos^4{(x)} \ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluate $\displaystyle\int \sin^5{(x)}\cos^4{(x)} \ dx$

How will I go about evaluating the given integral? I have absolutely no idea where to start, since substitution does not seem to lead anywhere.

Comment: Because of the identity $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$, you can trade out sines for cosines (or vice versa) *in pairs.*  Observe that if the power of $\sin x$ is odd, then you'll have one $\sin x$ left, so the substitution $u = \cos x$ will go nicely.

Comment: Notice that 6 people (5+ @SammyBlack ) came up with the same basic idea within 4 minutes.

Comment: Notice also that for any $a>0$, $$\int_{-a}^a \cos^4 x \sin^5 x \ \text{d}x = 0$$ since we're integrating an odd function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $u = \cos x$. Then $du = -\sin x \ dx$ and the integral

$$\int \sin^5 x \cos^4 x \ dx = -\int (1 - u^2)^2 u^4 \ du$$

Now you just have to integrate a polynomial in $u$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Let $u=\cos(x)$. Then find $u'$, and substitute in $du = u' dx$.
.
Also, rewrite $\sin^4(x)$ as $(\sin^2(x))^2$, then as $((1-\cos^2(x))^2$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** make the change of variables $u = \cos x$, using
$$
\sin^5 x = \sin x (1-\cos^2 x)^2
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\sin^5x = \sin x\cdot (1-\cos^2x)^2$, and use $u = \cos x$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use $$u=\cos(x), du=-\sin(x) $$ And also use $$\sin^2(x)=1-\cos^2(x)$$